# Micro controllers with high speed switching capabilities

Tags: switching, controller, motor-controller

I am planning a ESC for use with a 5500KV brushless motor, running on duel 4 cell Lithium Polymer batteries, I have noticed that in most speed controllers they use an Atmega to control the switching of the Mosfets, Is this a good controller to use for this purpose or should one use a better more suited controller, thats designed for high speed switching?

Comment: Define "high speed". AVRs are specified to run with up to a 20MHz clock, and I can't really see how a motor would need even a fraction of that.

Comment: The switching of the MosFETs is the simple part, as most microcontrollers have pulse-width-modulators that can do that for you. The "speed" of the microcontroller is more dependent on the control algorithm that you need to use.